# Mask a decimal without rounding

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to mask a decimal without rounding in ColdFusion?

Example:

45.5454

I want to get 45, not 46.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you want to handle negative numbers.

If you want `-45.5454` to be converted to `-45`, use **Fix()**.

If you want `-45.5454` to be converted to `-46`, use **Int()**.

If you're only dealing with positive numbers either will suffice.

[**Fix**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f87.html)

> **Description**
>   Converts a real number to an integer.
>
> **Returns**
>   If *number* is greater than or equal to 0, the closest integer less than or equal to *number*.
>   If *number* is less than 0, the closest integer greater than or equal to *number*.

```
myNumber=45.5454;
myResult=fix(myNumber);
```

[**Int**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f89.html)

> **Description**
>   Calculates the closest integer that is smaller than number. For example, it returns 3 for Int(3.3) and for Int(3.7); it returns -4 for Int(-3.3) and for Int(-3.7).
>
> **Returns**
>   An integer, as a string.

```
myNumber=45.5454;
myResult=int(myNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use int:

```
#Int(5.2)# = 5
#Int(2.9)# = 2
```

[Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f89.html)